# How to change method body bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation

Recently i have become interested in byte-code generation and manipulation.  In doing so i have decided that it would be cool to write a simple library that lets you change method bodies of a class.  I saw that it could be done with instrumentation, however it didn't seem like there is any method that allows you to change one method at a time, instead of providing byte-code for a whole new class.  I don't want to use any 3rd party libraries as that would defeat the whole purpose.  [ClassFileTransformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html) seems to be my best bet but it still does not do what i want to do.  I am doing this for a minecraft modding project and the licenses of other programs would be hard to keep in this situation.

Comment: Although you don't want to _use_ a 3rd party library, you can read the code for a 3rd party library to see how it's done. See http://www.javassist.org.

Comment: but javassist is for more than editing just method bodies so its whole structure is different

Comment: If you want to write a library that nobody cares about, then go for it. If you want to learn how things work and still your effort to be usable by others, it can happen if you contribute to some OSS project like https://www.jboss.org/byteman

Comment: Well actually i am writing the library to be used for game modding especially minecraft.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? How to write a classfile parser? That's just a matter of reading the JVM spec.